# 'conjoin' vs 'join'

Tags: difference

[conjoin](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conjoin)'s is defined as 'join', so what are the similarities and differences? Are there any etymological differences? I only recognise the term 'conjoined twins', and NOT 'joined twins'. Also, what are some formal terms describing this issue (in which a prefix or suffix fails to change the root's meaning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Join* is typically used when you are expressing that someone or something is becoming a member of a group.

[Examples for *join*](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/join).

Specifically, you wouldn't use *conjoin* to express when someone or something is becoming a member of a group.

> I conjoined the athletic club.

Doesn't sound right.

*Conjoin* is used when you want to unambiguously mean "two separate entities connecting together."

> The two rivers eventually conjoin.
>
> ... their attempts to conjoin two very different concepts

(examples from [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjoin))

Comment: Conjoin is used only to refer to both (or all) the things that are combined, whereas join often refers to just one of them, usually the smaller (as in an individual joining an organization, not vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

I can join a fitness club by becoming a member of the club, but I can easily cancel my membership and leave the club. Conjoined implies a more complete joining; where it is difficult or impossible to separate after joining.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the prior responses, but I've found that the distinction is less clear for the nouns "junction" and "conjunction", since both are typically used for situations where there has been a physical union or crossing of some kind. I'm not sure there is a clear difference between the nouns.